# Injecting ngControl in custom validator directive, causes cyclic dependency

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

i'm trying to create custom angular 2 validator directive, which inject NgControl like this :

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngModel][customValidator]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: CustomValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class CustomValidatorDirective implements Validator {
  private validateFunction: ValidatorFn;

  constructor(private control: NgControl) { };

}
```

But i get the following error:

> Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! NgControl

Does anyone know how i can workarround it, so i can access the ngControl after intialization?

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: The version is 2.0.0

Comment: can you remove providers section from here and add it into @NgModel({})?

Comment: Thanks @micronyks , looks like this solved the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Providers, Pipes, Directives* declaration are removed from ***@Compone*nt** or ***@Directi*ve** decorators after *RC6* or *RC7*. So you just need to remove

```
providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: CustomValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
```

from **directive**

and add it into **@NgModule({}) decorator**

```
@NgModule({
 ...
 providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: CustomValidatorDirective, multi: true}]

})
```

Comment: AFAIK `providers` property on a directive still works. It was not removed https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/core/src/metadata/directives.ts#L337 https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ngmodule-faq.html#!#q-component-or-module

Comment: @yurzui Thanks for the share.  Then problem could be not to provide such provider configuration here. Or may be providing providers here may create other instance or something.

Comment: I think putting the provider registration in the NgModule rather than the Directive will cause the validator to be shared across the modules which can access the CustomValidatorDirective. Obviously it will pollute NG_VALIDATORS when other directives also use it.

Answer (score 26):

You can inject NgControl via Injector to avoid cyclic dependency.

```
constructor(private _injector: Injector) { }

ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this._injector.get(NgControl))
}
```

Comment: It seems that `injector.get(NgControl)` is depreciated. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56061527/1730846) for an alternative solution.